# Finding the Kth largest element can be optimized to O(n) only if k is a constant?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, quicksort

There's a famous question posted on this site which asks about finding the $k$th largest element. Many answers are written there which optimized it and found algorithms with expectation of $O(n)$.

The thing I don't understand is....  Those algorithms wouldn't work if $k$ is dependent on $N$.  Therefore $k$ must be a constant.

But if it's a constant why isn't it easiest to simply loop like bubble sort for $k$ times?  So you pushed the $k$ largest elements to the end of the array. No?    Complexity would be $O(nk)$ but $k$ is a const so it would be $O(n)$.

Why do we need crazy algorithms like median of medians and using quicksort if this alone works?

Comment: Perfectly! Finding each Max take O(n).  Then all you have to do is repeat the process k times.  Since k isn't dependent on N wouldn't it be considered O of n?  This looks too simple so why do people use crazy algorithms like quicksort and stuff?

Comment: The key point is exactly that **$k$ may dependent on $N$**. For example, how can you find the median? Here $k$ is $N/2$ or $(N+1)/2$. Those "crazy" algorithms **work for that case**.

Comment: Mmm I thought about that.  But i would think if k isn't constant but n dependant.  Then.... Even using those 'crazy algorithms' wouldn't help much either.  As they too would run in n squared or nlgn times.  For example if you use a modified version of quicksort as suggested here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Median_selection_as_pivot_strategy then... I don't see any reason it wouldn't take n squared like quicksort in worst case.  So then again you haven't got any advantage compared to my simple algorithm

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand those algorithms. For one example, please check my answer to [Median of medians: bound on pivot position](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96972).

Comment: Ok I really do not understand them so well.   I would just rely on you.  Just tell me if this is correct.  What  you basically say is... That even if k isn't constant but grows as n grows these algorithms wouldn't take more than O(n), right?  Even though quicksort itself does take a higher order

Comment: Exactly. That is the power of those algorithms!

Answer (score 1):

The $k$th largest element can be found in time $O(n)$ for *all* $k$ using a *deterministic* algorithm. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Median_selection_as_pivot_strategy) or many textbooks, such as Cormen et al., Introduction to Algorithms.

Given the $k$th largest element, you can find the $k$ largest elements in $O(n)$ using a simple scan. If all elements are distinct, you just output all elements which are at least as large as the $k$th largest. Without this assumption, you output all elements which are strictly larger than that element, and then enough copies of the $k$th largest one.

Comment: Sorry I might be mixing things up.  Maybe what I am actually trying to achieve is finding all k largest elements and not just the Kth one.  Sorry for not being clear. I wrote it wrongly.  Wouldn't it still be O of n if I go about finding largest elements .  Each search for Max takes O of n and I need to iterate it k times.  So I got K*n.  So why do people offer much more complicated algorithms for this problem?

Comment: Even for just finding the Kth one.   I am sorry but I don't understand why does  your Wikipedia page go so far with crazy algorithms? I have a much simpler one.  As I noted in previous comment and in the question

Comment: Once you've found the $k$th largest element, you can find all others in $O(n)$ by going over all elements and comparing them to the $k$th largest element. This assumes all elements are distinct; otherwise you'll have to work a tiny bit harder.

Comment: Ok . But my algorithm is way simpler than the ones you presented...  in Wikipedia.  Why not use my simple algorithm?  Just find k times the max

Comment: Your algorithm takes quadratic time to find the median. Quickselect only takes linear time.

Comment: But isn't k a constant? It only takes kn if k is a const that would end up being o of n

Comment: No, $k$ could be anything at all.

Comment: But if K is n dependant... Then even quicksort as suggested in your Wikipedia page would run n squared , no?  I would think so since quick sort running time is n squared in worst case!

Comment: No, it will run in linear time.